# Movie/TV Series with a foam attacking commander in UFO submarine

Tags: story-identification

I have a really vague childhood memory of scene I saw on TV some 20 years ago. I'm from former eastern block, so it is totally possible that the source was much older.

In the scene there is a guy sitting in some kind of spaceship/submarine, but he's on top of the vehicle, in an trasparent dome. He is sitting in a command chair controlling the vehicle.

In this scene he is attacked by some kind of foam, which seeps through the dome and attacks him.

I have a feeling that the guy in question is Jean-Luc Picard, but none of my Star Trek fan friends seem to know about episode which would have this in it.

Comment: Sounds more like Dr. Who than Star Trek, except the command chair :-)

Comment: The Asimov novelization is a great read

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This sounds like the death scene of Donald Pleasance from [***Fantastic Voyage***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060397/) (1968) where the ship is attacked by white blood cells.

[image]

Comment: Wow thats it! Thank you so much!

Comment: I was three lines into reading this and knew it was fantastic voyage. well done @paulie_d

Answer (score 0):

Possibly Dr Who episode, "The Seeds of Death".  The Ice Warriors sent some kind of seeds to Earth via "T-Mat" from a moon base.  The seeds make foam go all over many major population centers. It kills and destroys.

I do not remember all the scenes; I don't even know if I saw all the installments.  So I do not know if there was a scene with a transparent dome and a command chair, with the foam seeping in.  Unlikely it would have been a spaceship or a submarine, but it could have been a control center (like the Weather Control Bureau, which the Ice Warrior needs to take over).

This was the Second Doctor, and his companions were Jamie and Zoe, if that rings any bells....